# Back emf (I think) is causing voltage surge - how to reduce it?

Tags: battery-charging, solenoid

In putting together a 24v charging system on an engine driven generator that didn't have one fitted, I connected a 24v bulb between a switched connection and the output of the generator in parallel with a solenoid that when powered pulls a rod that allows the engine to start. 
When the switch is operated, the power correctly lights up the bulb as it connects the battery to the generator. However, when the switch is turned off, the bulb suddenly flares up and fails. This I believe is because a back emf is generated in the solenoid when the power is turned off and this flows back around the circuit and through the bulb, burning it out.
Is this correct, and whatever the cause, how can it be avoided?
Thanks for any help given.

---

Thanks for your comments everybody. I will try to draw a diagram and put it on the forum when I have the time.

Comment: That is a lot of back EMF. You need large MOV's to clamp the EMF voltage level, and/or a current limiter for the bulb. Also, a charging circuit uses about 28 volts to charge a 24 volt battery. Can you come up with a simple connection diagram? It would help us understand where you need EMF protection, and what kind.

Comment: Consider using a higher voltage bulb? It'll be dimmer at steady state, but be more resilient to high voltage transients. A series resistor could also help some.

Comment: Enough back emf from a solenoid to kill a light bulb is unheard of. Most likely the generator has poor load regulation. When the solenoid opens there is a huge load dump. The generator can't reduce it's output fast enough and because the current has no where to go it manifests itself as a huge voltage spike.

Comment: Way too much hand waving, and it's all in one Great Wall of Text.  Closing.

Comment: If the light bulb is in parallel with the solenoid and there is no suppression diode or voltage clamp or snubber (as described by Marko), the light bulb gets hit with the full solenoid current when the solenoid is switched off. If the MOV voltage or zener voltage of Marko's solution are too high, there is still a chance of burning-out the light bulb or reducing it's life. A forward-biased diode in series with the light bulb should solve this, but I would recommend Marko's solution in addition. (I'm assuming since you mentioned a battery, that we are talking about DC at this point)

Answer (score 1):

Put a suppressor diode accros the coil, or a MOV. Don't fully understand where the bulb is. Using a diode with small forward voltage will cause the current to recirculate for longer time thus the rod will retract slowly, can damage the cranking gear. Using MOV you will get a fast decay, as the MOV has high resistance, but also the residual voltage will be high. Another possibility is to use diode and zener, the zener diode takes the surge at exact voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foitNd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>